# Could not load file or assembly 'VSLangProj80'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Its an Asp.net website . Running good on local development system . VS2010 and .NET 4 . When uploading to web server it throws an assembly could not be loaded error in my web.config file .

I sort it on google by changing framework from 3.5 to 4 will arise this error . My doubt is there any way to lock or persist the integrity of an assembly file through out the .NET versions .

My hosting server URL : http://ananth7453-001-site1.mywindowshosting.com/

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSLangProj80 is installed as part of Visual Studio which is why your site works on your development machine.  Copy the DLL to your project folder and then replace the reference in Visual Studio with the copy.

On my machine VSLangProj80 is located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\PublicAssemblies\VSLangProj80.dll`

Comment: Thanks for that . But its hard find that DLL in Explorer . Going to try that . Thanks @Philip

Answer (score 0):

I want to share the solution I encountered as I have the same issue encountered.  Over the years, our web server is installed with different Visual Studio programs, such as Shell (integrated mode) and Tools for Applications 2.0 ENU.  There's also Tools for Office Runtime.  It took us a while to isolate which of these installs conflicts to the application we are trying to install.

We found out that our application has the latest version of VSLangProj80.dll and the one in our server is using older version.  Without changing our build since it is working on our UAT environment, we manage to un-install the Tools for Application 2.0 ENU.  Removing this one out of our production server resolved this issue.